# Running npm start from ExecStart in systemctl service file

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, systemctl

I have the following service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=MyApp
After=syslog.target network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
WorkingDirectory=/opt/nodejs-sites/MyApp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/npm start
Environment=NODE_ENV=development
User=root
Group=root
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=MyApp

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is the error from /var/log/syslog

```
Oct 14 13:00:55 devu18 systemd[1]: Started myapp.
Oct 14 13:00:55 devu18 systemd[3203]: myapp.service: Changing to the requested working directory failed: No such file or directory
Oct 14 13:00:55 devu18 systemd[3203]: myapp.service: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory
Oct 14 13:00:55 devu18 systemd[1]: myapp.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Oct 14 13:00:55 devu18 systemd[1]: myapp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I for the life of me can't figure out why it's complaining of cannot find the file.  npm start from the same working directory works just fine, no problems.  Am I missing some permissions or +x or something somewhere?

Answer (score 12):

This error might happen due to the fact that the executable was run without environment.

### Here is a quick fix recipe

You can fix that by creating a Bash Script to do everything you need.

> **script.sh**

```sh
#! /bin/bash
source ${HOME}/.bashrc

cd /absolute/path/to/my/project
export NODE_ENV=development
npm start
```

Now change it's mode to be executable

```sh
chmod +x script.sh
```

Now we can create our service (located for instance in `/etc/systemd/system/my-project.service`)

> **my-project.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=My Project
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
ExecStart=/path/to/my/script.sh
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And now let's run it and enable it

```sh
systemctl start my-project
systemctl enable my-project
```

### Troubleshooting (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

This happened to me lately that for some reason systemctl couldn't effectively source `.bashrc` leaving me with an error `npm error does not exists` This is a workaround that helped me out.

Change the **script.sh** file's content into the following

```sh
#! /bin/bash
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"

cd /absolute/path/to/my/project
export NODE_ENV=development
npm start
```

Now your npm service should hopefully work.

---

*This solution was tested on:*

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, with Node version 14.16.0 installed via NVM (Node Version Manager)
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, with Node version 12.22.6 installed via NVM (Node Version Manager)
- CentOS 7, with Node version 12.22.6 installed via NVM (Node Version Manager)

Comment: Thank you this worked for me! I tried many different ways of configuring systemctl and this worked flawlessly.

EDIT: When I ran systemctl status, it said running which gave me false hope. Because when I ran systemctl status again, it stopped.

Comment: This is the best answer possible thanks for your commitment to this issue 

Comment: Debian 11, same troubleshoot like in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: i tried this , it is running but the app is not acceible , however  i can see the app while i manually do : npm run start

Answer (score 2):

```
/bin/npm --prefix $PATH start
```

This worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: to get npm path: `whereis npm` in my case: `/usr/local/bin/npm`