# The correct Gradle launch as a service

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, gradle, systemctl

I'm trying to create a service that will automatically launch the application using Gradle via a bash script. I create by analogy from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64353905/running-npm-start-from-execstart-in-systemctl-service-file) question. The bash script works correctly when launched from the console, but as a service it cannot start (below I will give the `systemctl status` output )

If I understood correctly, the service "does not understand" where it needs to find Gradle and run it. And if this is the case, then I need to specify the path in the variables, as it is done in the script for NodeJS.Maybe I searched badly, but I couldn't find any documentation on this topic. Perhaps you can tell me how doing it correctly.

the variables I'm talking about

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
```

bash script

```
#! /bin/bash
source ${HOME}/.bashrc

cd /home/valentin/Politehnika
gradle bootrun
```

service-file

```
[Unit]
Description=rString backend
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
ExecStart=/home/valentin/Politehnika/script.sh
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`systemctl status rString-backend.service` output

```
× rString-backend.service - rString backend
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rString-backend.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-04-27 10:01:51 UTC; 10min ago
   Main PID: 650047 (code=exited, status=127)
        CPU: 3ms

apr 27 10:01:51 rstring systemd[1]: rString-backend.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
apr 27 10:01:51 rstring systemd[1]: Stopped rString backend.
apr 27 10:01:51 rstring systemd[1]: rString-backend.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
apr 27 10:01:51 rstring systemd[1]: rString-backend.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
apr 27 10:01:51 rstring systemd[1]: Failed to start rString backend.
```

Comment: `${HOME}` I'm not sure that's going to be set in thise case but with `User=root` if it is set, it's not going to be `/home/valentin/`.

Comment: Idk, but the script for the web interface for nodeJS works with `${HOME}`. To be honest, I don't know how to write scripts correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it is impossible to start the project using Gradle (using the command `Gradle boot run`). Gradle creates a jar file `/your_project_name/build/libs/your_project_name-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` You can run it using a bash script as a service. In my case, it will look like this:

bash script

```
#! /bin/bash

cd /home/valentin/Politehnika/build/libs
java -jar rString-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

service-file

```
[Unit]
Description=rString backend
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
ExecStart=/home/valentin/Politehnika/script.sh
User=valentin

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After all these actions, just run the service using `systemctl`.

Maybe I should have done it that way at first, but my knowledge is very small. I hope I helped someone with a similar task. Here is a [link](https://fabianlee.org/2018/04/15/java-spring-boot-application-as-a-service-using-systemd-on-ubuntu-16-04/) to the article where I found the right answer. Perhaps there you will find more information on this topic.